# Xamarin azure InvokeAsyncApi

Tags: c#, .net, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently learning the different workarounds for Xamarin forms. I created a web service that searches for weather information and sends a HTTPResponseMessage. I keep getting a not found error every time I call the API.

> I change the route on the API and now I get a JSON parse error:

```
public async Task<string> weather(){
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>{ 
            {"lat", "33.92649137"}, {"lon", "-83.343567"}
        };

        try{
            var xml = await MobileService.InvokeApiAsync<string>("GetWeather", HttpMethod.Get, parameters);
            return xml;
        }catch (Exception e){
            DisplayAlert ("Error", e.ToString(), "Close");
            return "Failed";
        }


    }
```

My Webservice api:

```
    namespace MobileWeather.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : TableController<Weather>
    {
        protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(controllerContext);
            MobileServiceContext context = new MobileServiceContext();
            DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<Weather>(context, Request, Services);
        }

        public IQueryable<Weather> GetAllTodoItems()
        {
            return Query();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the weather information for a location based on the longitude and latitude values.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="lat">The latitude of the project site.</param>
        /// <param name="lon">The longitude of the project site.</param>
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/GetWeather")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetWeather(string lon, string lat)
        {

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php");
            string uri = "http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&FcstType=dwml";

            //create a weather item.
            Weather weather = new Weather();

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

            XDocument xml = new XDocument(); 
            xml = XDocument.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(), LoadOptions.None);

            /*
            weather.Temperature = Convert.ToInt32( xml.Descendants("temperature").Descendants("value").ElementAt(0).Value);
            weather.Lon = lon;
            weather.Lat = lat;
            weather.Precipitation = Convert.ToInt32(xml.Descendants("probability-of-precipitation").Descendants("value").ElementAt(0).Value);
            weather.Forecast = xml.Descendants("wordedForecast").Descendants("text").ElementAt(0).Value;
            weather.Hazard = xml.Descendants("hazards").Descendants("hazard-conditions").ElementAt(0).Value;
            weather.DateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
            */
            //query for the data we want!

            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {

                Content = response.Content
            };

        }

        public HttpResponseMessage Post()
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent("POST: Test message")
            };
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage Put()
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent("PUT: Test message")
            };
        }

    }
    }
```

Update => I change the route on the GetWeather method to [Route("api/GetWeather")] and now I am getting a parse error.

[image]

Comment: can you invoke your service from the browser?

Comment: Yes, It works just fine from my browser... I will update with full api code to see if that helps a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, It would seen the route needed to point to api/GetWeather for my mobile client to find it. As for the parsing error, I will fix it as soon as Azure comes back from being down. The error so far appears to be cause because InvokeApiAsync expects a JSON object by default and I am responding with a HTTPResponseMessage.